# Object models for DyanamoDbTable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I’m entirely new to DynamoDB
After researching I concluded to use ONE table for app design.

So I have a DynamoDB Table as `PK, SK, CONTENT, < MANY OTHER ATTRIBUTES>`.
My model in java looks something like below

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = “my-data")
public class MyData {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "pk")
    private String partitionKey;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "sk")
    private String sortKey; 

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "content")
    private String content; //non queried content, I’ll save as JSON


    //below are the attributes which I MIGHT want to queries on later maybe be I'll end up creating GSI or LSI

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field1")
    private String field1;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field2")
    private String field2;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field3")
    private String field3;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field4")
    private String field4;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field5")
    private String field5;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field6")
    private String field6;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "field7")
    private String field7;

}
```

Now what I want is,
I want to have a different class let's call it `MySearchableData` having field1 to field7. And then I want to have `MySearchableData` inside `MyData`  like below.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = “my-data")
public class KaleidoscopeData {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "pk")
    private String partitionKey;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "sk")
    private String sortKey; // ISO 8601 time string

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "content")
    private String content; //non queried JSON content  

     // ?? what annotation to use here       
    private MySearchableData mysearchableData;      

}

public class MySearchableData{

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
    private String field5;
    private String field6;
    private String field7;
}
```

**Question is**.
What annotation to use so all these fields from `MySearchableData`  will be treated as attributes in AWS `my-data` tables

---

**UPDATE**
I am unable to find any annotation for nested classes at AWS documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html

Comment: Instead of composition, you can use inheritance.

Comment: Dont try such tricks, here is an example...... A CAR has ENGINE , but a CAR is NOT an ENGINE...We can not simply move composition into inheritance without considering the domain model... What we can do however (with a compromise) is, to  have all the field of ENGINE engine class into CAR and that's a bad code but the CAR model is still semantically valid. thats  what I have done above in but its not clean code. .